# Redshift copy results in unordered rows

Tags: amazon-redshift

According to [Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-sort-key-order.html):

> Load your data in sort key order to avoid needing to vacuum.
>
> As long as each batch of new data follows the existing rows in your
>   table, your data will be properly stored in sort order, and you will
>   not need to run a vacuum. You don't need to presort the rows in each
>   load because COPY sorts each batch of incoming data as it loads.

The sort key is a timestamp and the data is loaded as it comes in. 200 rows are loaded at a time. However the rows are 99% unsorted. Why are so many rows unsorted?

Comment: How can you tell that 99% rows are unsorted?

Comment: When I run `select unsorted, "table" from svv_table_info;` the "unsorted" value is 99.99

Answer (score 0):

You should double check the data you insert, as if your newly data is sorted by the SORTKEY **and** it intended to be placed at the end of the table, only then the VACUUM will not be necessary. If you have at least one row that is placed after the intentional data to be loaded, this data will be placed into an unsorted region in Redshift, which causes your data to be unsorted.

See [this example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/vacuum-load-in-sort-key-order.html) for further information.
Also, read about [VACUUM](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Reclaiming_storage_space202.html) process.